# Can I replace a string without find string in PHP?

Tags: php

I have text file(test.txt) like this.

**test.txt**

```
"HOME" => "НАЧАЛО",
"REWARDS" => "НАГРАДИ",
"LEADERBOARDS" => "КЛАСАЦИИ",
"LOGIN | SIGN UP" => "ВХОД / РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ",
"STORE" => "МАГАЗИН",
"LOGOUT" => "ИЗХОД",
"SET" => "ПОТВЪРДИ
```

Now i want replace some word from my php flie(test.php).

**test.php**

```
$new_word = "НАГРАДИ123";
$en_word  = "REWARDS";
```

I am using file handling to write a file. My question is can I replace the word **НАГРАДИ** into `$new_word` in text.txt using `$en_word`.??

**Result must be like this.**

```
"HOME" => "НАЧАЛО",
"REWARDS" => "НАГРАДИ123",
"LEADERBOARDS" => "КЛАСАЦИИ",
"LOGIN | SIGN UP" => "ВХОД / РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ",
"STORE" => "МАГАЗИН",
"LOGOUT" => "ИЗХОД",
"SET" => "ПОТВЪРДИ
```

"REWARDS" => **"НАГРАДИ123"**,

Is this possible?? please help me.

Comment: Why you are using a text file (test.txt) instead of a php file ? Is there a problem to use a php file (test.php) and keep the array in it ?

Comment: No problem. if php file mean can I do this?

Comment: If you have difficulties with my answer you may ask me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question then I think you need to replace Non-English words with English words and to do so you can use

```
$original_words=array(
    "HOME" => "НАЧАЛО",
    "REWARDS" => "НАГРАДИ",
    "LEADERBOARDS" => "КЛАСАЦИИ",
    "LOGIN | SIGN UP" => "ВХОД / РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ",
    "STORE" => "МАГАЗИН",
    "LOGOUT" => "ИЗХОД",
    "SET" => "ПОТВЪРДИ"
);
$english_words=array(
    "HOME"=>"HOME",
    "REWARDS"=>"REWARDS",
    "LEADERBOARDS" => "LEADERBOARDS",
    "LOGIN | SIGN UP" => "LOGIN | SIGN UP",
    "STORE" => "STORE",
    "LOGOUT" => "LOGOUT",
    "SET" => "SET"
);
$new_words=str_ireplace($original_words, $english_words, $original_words);
print_r($new_words);
```

but to do this you need to change your test.txt to test.php and keep $original_words array in it and include it like, include('test.php'); before str_ireplace call.

Answer (score 0):

You need str_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Read the contents of the file, perform your replace, then write everything back to the file (Assuming you want to do so).

Comment: Why you are using a text file (test.txt) instead of a php file ? Is there a problem to use a php file (test.php) and keep the array in it ?